# How to read sexp from file

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

If I write a file using

```
(with-open-file (s "~/example.sexp" :direction :output)
           (write '(1 2 3) :stream s)
           (write '(4 5 6) :stream s)
           (write '(7 8 9) :stream s))
```

A file is created containing

```
(1 2 3)(4 5 6)(7 8 9)
```

But when I attempt to open and read it using

```
(setf f (open "~/example.sexp"))
(read :input-stream f)
```

I get an ":INPUT-STREAM is not of type STREAM" error.

```
(type-of f)
```

returns STREAM::LATIN-1-FILE-STREAM which looks like it is at least *close* to what I need.  What is the difference?

How can I read the lists I've written to the file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got the arguments to `READ` wrong. It should be simply `(read f)`, not `(read :input-stream f)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use with-open-file:

```
(with-open-file (s "~/example.sexp")
  (read s))
```

Or even:

```
(with-open-file (*standard-input* "~/example.sexp")
  (read))
```

:input is the default direction.